# yes/ No :Is $f$ is uniformly continious .?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let $(X,T)$ be the subspace  of $\mathbb{R}$  given by $X= [0,1] \cup [2,4] $. Define $f :(X, T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 , \text {if  x} \in [0,1] \\ 2  \ \text {if x} \in [2,4]  \end{cases}$.
Is $f$ is uniformly  continious ?

My attempt : I know that $f$ is continious  since $f^{-1}( 2,4)= 2$ is open in $(X,T)$

Im confused that it is U.C or not ?

Comment: Note that "uniformly continuous" is not topological concept. That is, if you just specify a topology $T$ for the domain $X$, it is meaningless to talk about whether $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. What you need is a "uniformity" but not just a "topology" on the domain.

Comment: One way to think about "uniformity" is that "uniformity" is something generated by a family of separating pseudo-metrics. You may consult Kelley's General Topology.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan: Uniform continuity is, however, a metric space concept, and that’s clearly what is intended here.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott The symbol $T$ usually denotes a topology. If one is considering $X$ as a metric space, he should at least write $(X,d)$ or state it explicitly.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan: In this case it would actually be better simply to write $X$: writing $d$ isn’t much better than writing $T$, since it need not refer to the usual metric. But in all of these variants the `real-analysis` tag and the ‘subspace of $\Bbb R$’ in the question make it pretty clear that the usual real analysis notion is meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real-valued function $f$ on a subspace $X$ of $\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. For your function this is the case, because for any $\epsilon>0$ you can take $\delta=1$: if $|x-y|<1$, then, as you can easily check, $f(x)=f(y)$ (why?), so $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is uniformly continuous w.r.t the usual metric from $\mathbb R$. Take $0<\delta<1$.

Note that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies either $x$ and $y$ are both in $[0,1]$ or both in $[2,4]$. Hence $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon$.